# How to sort filtered data in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, filtering

I have a worksheet populated with data.  I need to filter the data that could  only show the info `w/in 5 miles`.  Once the data is filtered to `w/in 5 miles`, I need to sort the variance column in ascending order.  I used a record macro and attempted to incorporate it.  The filtering works fine but I get an error saying:

> Compile Error: Expected Array

when I run it.  Here is a snippet of my code.  When the error pops up, the `Range` is highlighted on the 6th line of code.

```
.Worksheets("Market Work").Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
.Worksheets("Market Work").Range("$A$1:$Q$" & RowLast2).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    "w/in 5 miles"


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Market Work").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Market Work").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "G2:G112"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Market Work").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:Q112")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Have you considered sorting first and then filtering?

Comment: I tried that and got the same error....in the same place

Answer (score 1):

Following code will help you...

```
Sheets("Finnet").Select
Sheets("Finnet").AutoFilterMode = False
Sheets("Finnet").Range("A1", Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft)).Select
Sheets("Finnet").Range(Selection, Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).AutoFilter
Sheets("Finnet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
Sheets("Finnet").AutoFilter.Sort.Header = xlYes
Sheets("Finnet").AutoFilter.Sort.Apply
Sheets("Finnet").AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: I tried the code above...it highlighted "Range" in the third line and gave the same error message.